# how to pass regex as function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following python function which takes query which is string as an input but instead of just passing simple string I would like pass it as regex...how can I do it. here query is string which contains alphabet/number/symbol for example `"MSEB-1020-MSK-01" and "MSEB-102*-MSK-**"`

```
def function(string: str):

    f_df = df_.loc[
        df_["Company"].str.contains(string)
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def function(df, string):

    f_df = df.loc[df["company"].str.contains(query, regex=True)] # `regex = True`, allows you to pass regex expresion

    return f_df  

df_query = function(df_benchmark, "whatever_your_regex_is")
```

hope this works for you

Comment: The explanation police want to know your location

Comment: that was a funny comment, you could answer and help us both, haha i am not an expert at pandas, i am still learning , and answering questions helps, but sure here is my address `127.0.0.1`